# Block file access using http

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have website in which we are creating pdf documents and
to store those pdf doc we have created dynamic folders based on user Id and some other ids like

```
upload/user_1/usr_12/somefile.pdf
```

folder user_1 and usr_12 are created on dynamic basis.

If any one can type http://mydomain.com/upload/user_1/usr_12/somefile.pdf at address bar it asked to download that file how I can restrict that?
I know I can use .htaccess file in upload folder but this will only block to listing files, but what If any one have exact url?

How to restrict access of exact url(as per above example http://mydomain.com/upload/user_1/usr_12/somefile.pdf)

Comment: I would recommend rewriting urls, such as `user_1/usr_12/somefile.pdf` -> `getfile.php?user=1&usr=12&file=somefile.pdf`. Then you can place all the authentication in `getfile.php`. You should also move all the PDF files off the document root. That will make sure only people who are authenticated to view those files are viewing them through `getfile.php`.

Comment: but still If any one having(with in our team or ex-team member) that path he/she can access that file and I wanted to restrict that access.

Comment: No because you would place checks within `getfile.php` to make sure that they are logged in. The link `user_1/usr_12/**` would act as an alias for `getfile.php?***` and getfile would first check if they are allowed to access that file, then retrieve the file from off the document root. In other words, it's not possible to access any PDF without going through getfile.php.

Comment: [`Deny from all`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html)

Comment: @DaveChen Write as an Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following code.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^upload/(.*)$ /someurl [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside `/upload/.htaccess` have this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /upload/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /upload/\w+/\w+/[^.]+\.pdf [NC]
RewriteRule ^\w+/\w+/[^.]+\.pdf$ - [F,NC]
```